# search for a certain text between within a range of a certain timestamp with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have worked with Elasticsearch and have done some research on the Internet how to query data with a certain text and how to query data within a range of timestamp, using Elasticsearch PHP Client API. Now I would like to combine these two queries in one. Lets say search for a certain text and within a range of a certain timestamp. Can someone please tell me how to do that using Elasticsearch PHP Client API? Thanks in advanced! I have searched on the Internet but still cannot combine these two queries in one :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a bool query, the logic here is that the record must fall within a date range and should also contain the text in the `textfield` field. **You could have both query conditions within the must clause.**

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "datefield": {
                            "gte": "from",
                            "lte": "to"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "textfield": {
                            "query": "Name",
                            "boost": 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE - OR MUST HAVE BOTH**

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "datefield": {
                            "gte": "from",
                            "lte": "to"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "textfield": {
                            "query": "Name",
                            "boost": 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After using your example, it is right to search for data with a certain text within a range of a certain timestamp but some data does not even contain that searching text, they are also present. How can I improve that?

Comment: I note that the data with the searching text comes on top and other data comes at the bottom. But other data should not be present because they do not contain the searching text.

Comment: It depends on analyzer you are using on the field, how ES is breaking down the text into tokens. If you want to have an exact match I would set the field to not analyzed and this will return only results that match exactly what you want. You can also move it into the must as well. Have a look at this link for multi field - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html ... Apologies if this doesnt answer your question I did try and understand it as best as I could

Comment: @O Connor: It is mentioned in the answer put both queries in the `must` statement. Read the [bool-query docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). If you have further troubles with that, please improve your question and post your current query and sample data.

Comment: I just replace "should" by "must" and it works fine. @Nate what do you mean with set the field to not analyzed and how to do that?

Comment: @OConnor you can read about this on ES website, have a look at this post to help you understand how ES deals with the data - http://blog.smeef.co.uk/elasticsearch-data-structure/ ... If this question solved your problem, dont forget to mark as correct :)

Comment: @OConnor I've update the answer with how the query should look rather than having two `must` clauses

Comment: I have followed your update clauses and it works fine. How can I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: The tick beside the question I believe. Good practise on Stack Overflow to mark all correct answers as correct.